# How to extract data from HDF file?

Tags: python, r, hdf5, h5py

I have an HDF file (.h5) which has the following hierarchy
[image]

I have never worked with this kind of data. I think that 'barcodes' should be my columns and 'features/names' should be my rows, 'data' should be the values. How do I extract it in the form of a barcodesXnames dataframe preferably in Python?

I tried this

```
    filename = "filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5"

    with h5py.File(filename, "r") as f:
    data = f.get('matrix/data')
    dataset=np.array(data)
    print(dataset)
```

but it gives me an array of data like [1 1 1 ... 2 1 2]

Comment: You have a formatting error in your post (you need indention after `with h5py`). I assume this is correct in your code. Also, you don't need to declare `data` or use `np.array()` to get a Numpy array. You can use this statement:  `dataset=f['matrix/data'][:]`. Alternatively, you can use the `data` object similar to a Numpy array. You can add `print(data.dtype)` and `print(data.shape)` to get type and shape info for this dataset.

Comment: One more idea: Your image looks like it is from HDFView. If so, you can use it to get details about datasets. Click on  a dataset (/matrix/data for example) and the "General Object Info" tab lists dimensions (number and sizes). When you double-click on the dataset, it will open in another window where you can view the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
import h5py
f = h5py.File('filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5','r') 
f.keys()
f['data']
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

With datasets named `indptr` and `indicies`, I think `matrix` is supposed to be a `scipy.sparse` matrix.

To load this you need to use `h5py` docs and `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` docs

```
csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), [shape=(M, N)])
    is the standard CSR representation where the column indices for
    row i are stored in ``indices[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]`` and their
    corresponding values are stored in ``data[indptr[i]:indptr[i+1]]``.
    If the shape parameter is not supplied, the matrix dimensions
    are inferred from the index arrays.
```

Roughly then:

```
import h5py
from scipy import sparse

f = h5py.File(...)
gp = f['matrix']
data = gp['data'][:]
indptr = gp['indptr'][:]
indices = gp['indices'][:]
shape = gp['shape'][:]

M = sparse.csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=shape)

M.A   # dense numpy array equivalent (don't do this is `shape` is large)
```

`data`, `indptr` etc should all be numpy arrays.  `shape` will also be an array, probably 2 numbers, e.g. `np.array([1000, 2000])`.

Comment: I agree. However, I got an error "ValueError: index pointer size (4482) should be (20622)" doing that. I think the reason might be that 'data' values are not assigned for each matrix cell. There are 11798579 values while there are more cells in the matrix which shape should be 4481(unique cells)*20621(unique genes).

Comment: What is `shape`?

Comment: @Yulia Kentieva, a sparse matrix is convenient when you have an array with lots of zeros (aka "sparse"). Only the non-zero terms are stored, along with indices to their locations (the zero terms are NOT saved). Based on your numbers, your data is 87% sparse, so it makes sense (calculated from: 11798579/(4481*20621). `csr_matrix` expects the `shape=` argument to be a tuple. If the `shape` variable is a `np.array` of shape `(2,)` you need to convert to a tuple, like this: `shape=tuple(shape)`. Once you have the sparse matrix `M`, use the other `csr_matrix` methods to operate on it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to start with an introduction to HDF5 data schema/objects. You need to understand this to work effectively with HDF5 data. There are 2 basic entities: 1) Groups and 2) Datasets. They are similar to Folders and Files on your computer. Groups are like Folders, and Datasets are like Files that hold data. (Note: Neither of these are columns or row names -- you get that info by interrogating each dataset).

Groups use a Folder icon in your image of the file layout. You have 2 Groups.
They are:

```
/matrix
/matrix/features
```

Datasets have a different icon. You have 10 Datasets, 5 saved under each Group.
They are:

```
/matrix/barcodes
/matrix/data
/matrix/indices
/matrix/indptr
/matrix/shape

/matrix/features/_all_tag_keys
/matrix/features/feature_name
/matrix/features/genome
/matrix/features/id
/matrix/features/name
```

I created a simple example to interrogate your model and output Groups/Datasets. In addition, it outputs the dtype and shape for datasets. This should help you pragmatically "see" what you have and compare to your image.

- Dtype is the datatypes (int, float, string), and the field/column
  names (if they are defined).
- Shape depends on the dataset definition. For simple NumPy arrays, it is the dimension in all directions. For mixed datatypes (record arrays) it is the number of rows.

Code segment below:

```
import h5py

def visitor_func(name, node):
    if isinstance(node, h5py.Group):
        print(node.name, 'is a Group')
    elif isinstance(node, h5py.Dataset):
       if (node.dtype == 'object') :
            print (node.name, 'is an Object Dataset')
       else:
            print(node.name, 'is a Dataset')
            print ('Dataset dtype=', node.dtype)
            print ('Dataset shape=', node.shape) 

    else:
        print('Node is unknown type: ', node.name)           

print ('testing hdf5 file')
with h5py.File('filtered_feature_bc_matrix.h5','r') as h5f:
    h5f.visititems(visitor_func)
```

Comment: thank you. This is helpful to understand the file structure. However, I still do not understand how to extract the data from those datasets. I have a feeling that I need to 'construct' a matrix from the datasets. All the datasets except 'shape' are one-dimensional arrays. Dataset 'data' has a shape (11798579,), 'barcode'  - (4481,), 'features/name'  - (20621,). I suppose that 'indices' (11798579,) and 'indptr' (4482,) are responsible for putting the 'data' values in right cells of the matrix.

Comment: Getting the data is the easy part. No need to create an array in advance. You can get the barcode data with either 1) `barcode_dset=h5f['/matrix/barcodes']` or 2) `barcode_arr=h5f['/matrix/barcodes'][:]`. The first is a 'Numpy-like' h5py object. The second is a Numpy array. Which is 'better' depends on what you need to do with the data. (To interpret the data, you will need to understand the schema.)  Use the same method for other datasets (for example to get the data in '/matrix/features/name', use: `h5f['/matrix/features/name']`.

Comment: My h5 file contains information about gene expression levels for each cell. There are 4481 cells ('barcodes' array) and 20621 genes (any of 'features/name' or 'features/id' arrays). Normally, this kind of data is presented in a matrix cellsXgenes with gene expression values in each matrix cell. In this case, I think that those values are contained in 'data' dataset.

Comment: How do I extract a matrix that contains all that information (cells, genes, values) rather than extracting each dataset?

Comment: Datasets are read individually. From what you described, I think you will have to read the data, and reassemble the cellsXgenes matrix of values. I suspect indices and indptr are the keys to reassembling the matrix. Ideally, you have the schema (from the creator of the HDF5 file) that documents each dataset's contents. If not, it's a bit of a puzzle. Note: The Python/Numpy "matrix" object is called an array. It can have N dimensions.

Comment: @hpaulj is on to something regarding with **Scipy sparse matrix**. I recommend his answer (after you diagnose the cause of the error message).